# Unique Mysql Field based if another field is the same

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to find an answer for this, likely because trying to find the words is a bit difficult and Google doesn't have a clue what I'm on about.

I have a table of stock

```
+-------+------------+-----------+
| id    | product_id | serial    |
+-------+------------+-----------+
| 1     | 1          | 1234      |
+-------+------------+-----------+
| 2     | 2          | 1234      |
+-------+------------+-----------+
```

I need to make the serial number unique only if the the product id matches, so the above example is perfectly fine, however, the one below is not

```
+-------+------------+-----------+
| id    | product_id | serial    |
+-------+------------+-----------+
| 1     | 1          | 1234      |
+-------+------------+-----------+
| 2     | 1          | 1234      |
+-------+------------+-----------+
```

How would I go about doing this?
Thanks

Comment: I would start by looking at row number variables.

Comment: It's a question about updating existing records or about preventing duplicates for new records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE  `stock` ADD UNIQUE (
`product_id ` ,
`serial `
);
```

Comment: Wow that simple, thank you for the speedy reply. That's going onto my snippet site